# Why can't I type into these textareas?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, spine.js

I have been pulling out my hairs trying to figure out why the `textarea` tags on a particular page can't be typed into. From what I can see, they are not disabled or readonly, but I can't type into them on any browser.

Please take your FireBugs and Chrome Developer Tools and [help me out here](http://korhal.andrewmao.net/~mao/peer-prediction/#/exitsurvey).

Other info: this is a single-page JS app built with Spine, using npm-browserified packages. But I don't see why that would cause any issues with `textarea`.

Comment: There is some JavaScript that's blocking the `keypress` event.  Typing `$(document).off('keypress')` in the console fixes the textareas.

Comment: Something in that application.js file is preventing it. Possibly a `return false` on `keypress` or something.

Comment: You may want to put out a version of application.js that is not minified for easier debugging...

Comment: Replaced with non-minified version. Sorry about that. Yes, the other programmer working on this mentioned something about `keypress`es. That must be it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Way down, towards the bottom of the JavaScript file is this line:

```
$(document).keypress(this.keyPressed);
```

And then lower down is:

```
Tutorial.prototype.keyPressed = function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
```

This is, obviously, disabling the `keypress` event for everything on the page.